# Exclude Featured Posts in Wordpress 'Recent Posts' Function

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Can I use the "exclude" array in the `wp_get_recent_posts` function to exclude Featured Posts? I have a plugin called NS Featured Posts which pulls featured posts through a key in the wp query i.e.:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'meta_key'   => '_is_ns_featured_post',
        'meta_value' => 'yes'
    ) 
);
```

could I somehow use this to target and exclude NS Featured Posts in the `wp_get_recent_posts` call e.g.:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'exclude' => (the ns featured posts)
    ));
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tested it now and getting posts without a certain meta key in one query is not possible.

But: You can exclude them from another query like so:

```
    $featured_posts = get_posts( [
        'meta_key' => '_is_ns_featured_post',
        'meta_value' => 'yes',
        'fields'     => 'ids',
    ] );

    query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => $featured_posts ) );

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $output .= '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that (didn't work) which is why I was wondering if I could use the exclude option to do this. Seems like this should be a pretty ubiquitous logic...

Comment: Jep, I should have tested it. It really doesn't work by just querying for empty meta. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Functions such as `wp_get_recent_posts()` can accept all of the same arguments as `WP_Query`. While the documentation only lists a handful of parameters, the full set are available to you.

You had suggested using `exclude` in your query however that's going to want the IDs of the posts to exclude. You could of course grab those first but that's not going to be the most efficient solution.

The way to do this in a single query is with meta query options. The posts are being tagged with a meta key and a meta query will allow you to exclude those. You'll need to check both for the existence of the meta key and the value being 'yes'.

Example:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_is_ns_featured_post',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_is_ns_featured_post',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    )
) );
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: That's actually similar to what I had in my answer before actually testing it. The meta key/value for unfeatured posts is not set so this doesn't work.

Comment: @pjldesign I've updated the answer to address the other commenters point.

Comment: @user127091 You're right! I've just updated my answer to include a check for whether the meta key actually exists.